# Cylindrical - wondering why my integral doesn't work

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm wondering why my computation doesn't work and if someone could correct me on my misunderstanding.I got the correct answer via Spherical coordinates, but not by cylindrical.

Find the volume enclosed by the surfaces $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 + (z-2)^2 = 2^2$ and $\rho$ is the angle from positive $z$-axis.
This is my working:
In spherical coordinates,
$$V = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{0}^{2} \rho ^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\theta d\phi + \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4 \cos \phi} \rho ^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\theta d\phi = \frac{10\pi}{3}.$$
Now, my derivation in cylindrical coordinates gives me:
$$V = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{2 - \sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} r dz dr d\theta = \frac{8\pi}{3}.$$
I've done this repeatedly, even with cartesian coordinates (which support my cylindrical answer, but I know the answer for spherical is correct).

Comment: Why do you have $r$ running from $0$ to $2$?

Comment: Did you mean "$\rho$ is the *distance* from the $z$-axis", perhaps?

Comment: And in the first integral, why does $\varphi$ go from $0$ to $\pi/3$? When you say "the volume enclosed by the surfaces", you mean the volume of the intersection of their interiors, right? We're talking about two overlapping solid balls, no?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Isn't that the range of r? I deduced from the x-y plane, the region determined by $x,y$ in their respective region (which is a circle of radius 2, centred at the origin).

Comment: @JohnHughes Sorry, I had meant that $\phi$ was that angle, not $\rho$.  
Yep, the overlapping solid spheres. So the region of intersection. I figured it out by splitting up the possible values of $\phi$, by examining the $y-z$ plane.  
Also, found this Q (in spherical) exactly here as well: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/volume-enclosed-by-two-spheres-using-spherical-coordinates.871272/

Comment: Well, each ball has radius 2, but the region where they intersect doesn't extend all the way to their equators. The intersection of the two given spheres is a circle at $z=1$. What is its radius?

Comment: Ah, right, $\sqrt{3}$. Much appreciated, that was very silly.